# Why is include_role processing one host at a time?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I've created an auxiliary role to build software packages from source. However, when I try to include it in a loop -- looping over a dictionary describing the packages. It works, but, when I include it from another role's task:

```yaml
- name: Build packages
  include_role:
    name: native-package
  loop: "{{ srcpkgs | dict2items }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: package
    label: "{{ package.key }}"
  when: srcpkgs is defined
```

The `srcpkg` is a hash describing packages. One example of package-entry is:

```yaml
srcpkgs:
  python:
    ver:    "3.7.0"
    sha:    "0382996d1ee6aafe59763426cf0139ffebe36984474d0ec4126dd1c40a8b3549"
    url:    "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/%%ver%%/Python-%%ver%%.tar.xz"
    confargs: >-
      --without-pymalloc
      --disable-ipv6
      --with-system-expat
      --enable-optimizations
      --with-lto
      --prefix={{ prefix }}
      --with-openssl={{ prefix }}
      --with-ssl-default-suites=openssl
    alltarg:    profile-opt
    env:
      - 'GITTAG="echo builtFor={{ inventory_hostname }}"'
```

I see, that it is applied to *one machine at a time*, instead of to all machines in parallel (`forks` is set to `11`), which causes it to take unnecessarily long time:

```
TASK [include_role : native-package] 
TASK [native-package : Create tmpdir]
ok: [host1]
TASK [native-package : Download package]
ok: [host1]
TASK [native-package : Extract]
ok: [host1]
... more tasks on host1 ...
TASK [native-package : Create tmpdir]
ok: [host2]
....
```

I would expect the output to be:

```
TASK [include_role : native-package] 
TASK [native-package : Create tmpdir]
ok: [host1]
ok: [host2]
... more hosts ...
ok: [hostN]
TASK [native-package : Download package]
ok: [host1]
ok: [host1]
... more hosts ...
ok: [hostN]
... more tasks ...
```

Also, the label I specify does not appear anywhere and I don't know, which package is being built at a particular iteration...

How do I improve the above?

(Using ansible-2.6.2 and Python-3.6.6 here.)

*Update*: the problem seems to be triggered by the reference to `inventory_hostname` in the dictionary. Indeed, if I remove the parts of it, where the hostname is mentioned (thus making the entries identical for all hosts?), the included role is executed as I'd expect. This seems like a bug, and I'll try to file one...

Comment: Impossible to understand, yet answer, without knowing `srcpkgs` and what's in your `....`. Please have a look at the Help Center: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Question expanded...

Comment: Copy the code from the question to a new file. Create a role with a single file `./roles/native-package/tasks/main.yml` with the following content `- ping:`. Remove `ansible.cfg`, create an inventory with the following content: `host 1\nhost2` where hosts resolve to real machines which you can connect to. Run `ansible -i inventory playbook.yml`. If you get the result corresponding to the one after "*one machine at a time*" explanation, you have created an MCVE.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is a [known problem](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/36978) -- since Ansible-2.4, at least.

It strikes, when the dictionary being looped-over -- or any other aspect of the iteration -- is *host-specific*. Such as, for example, when it includes references to `inventory_hostname`.